# Generating a image with a background corresponding to a gray contrast

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I need to generate an image which only consists of a gray background and I would need this grayscale-contrast to correspond to the grayscale range of [0,255]. This because I base it on a real life image which will, for example in the case below, have a contrast value around 199. I need this for the training material for a machine learning application.

The problem I have now is that, when I generate an array consisting of a specific grayscale-contrast, it returns a black picture. This code:

```
background_array = np.ones((1200, 750))
background_array = np.array(background_array * 199,dtype=np.uint8)
plt.imshow(background_array, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

generates a completely black image, and if I change `plt.imshow(background_array, cmap="gray")` to `plt.imshow(background_array, cmap="gray_r")`, it is completely white.

I have tried to convert it into a an image with the following line `grayscale_img=Image.fromarray(background_array,mode="L")` but it does not help.

HOWEVER, if I do this "dirty" trick:

```
background_array = np.ones((1200, 750))
background_array = np.array(background_array * 199,dtype=np.uint8)
background_array[0,0]=255
background_array[0,1]=0
plt.imshow(background_array, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

then I get the desired shade of gray with two pixels of which one is black and one is white. So I have come to the conclusion that the issue lies in the range of the contrast used in the array. But I am getting annoyed at this and wondering why it does not work. I have spammed chatGPT with this but it does not get anything done. I would also love and explanation behind this, because it is interesting to me why it does not work.

Comment: Since you only have one color, matplotlib is automatically determining the bounds for the colormap. Trying adding in `vmin = 0, vmax = 255` as arguments in `imshow`.

Comment: This makes the correct contrast, thanks! Such an easy solution... However, do you happen to know if the generated pictures contrast is explicitly determined by the vmin and vmax parameters or is it just for visualizing? I mean, will my generated picture be regarded as a grayscale image with the single contrast value of 199 for image-processing if I generate it as I did above?

Comment: It should once it's saved in a file format that recognizes it as an 8-bit grayscale image. Imshow is built around showing image array with arbitrary values, so it makes no assumptions and just tries to stretch the whole range of numbers across the entire colormap. You can always just test this by saving an image and opening it.

Comment: Another funny thing I found is even without setting a vmin/vmax, just adding a `plt.colorbar()` also gives you a more gray contrast, though it still uses a reduced range of values.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and tips. I actually ended up going with a white background generated in a different way. In that case, the background is generated directly as a PIL RGB image with fill=(255,255,255) and I convert it to grayscale using ImageOps. After that I write with black on it. Atm I cannot see it miss-interpreting this but here I do have the whole range.